# Only the last variable in sequence being written

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

I have perhaps the most perplexing issue I've ever had with PHP. Please see the following code:

```
public $profile;

 public $account;

  function __construct(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
      $this->$profile = $_SESSION['user_profile'];
      $this->$account = $_SESSION['user_account'];
      echo "<script> alert('".$this->$profile->forename."'); </script>"; //Shows nothing
    }else{
      unset($_SESSION['user_profile']);
      unset($_SESSION['user_account']);
    }
  }
```

For some reason, it seems that either `$this->$profile` will be written or `$this->$account` will be written, but only if it is the last one. In the situation above, if I moved the profile line to be after the account line, it would be written. However, in this case it is not.

Both `$_SESSION` variables are objects retrieved from an SQL statement, and their assignments are valid as accessing either of the variables directly (eg. `$_SESSION['user_profile']->forename`) works fine.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Try using `$this->profile` and `$this->account` instead of `$this->$profile`, `$this->$account`

Comment: well spotted @RyanHipkiss

Comment: @RyanHipkiss That seems to have worked. Do you know why? I don't think I've had that trouble before. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: With the extra dollar sign they are `variable variables` so probably they go to `$this->null` in both cases and overwrite each other.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but your code looks like you are trying to access a member variable.

Replace this:

```
$this->$profile
$this->$account
```

With this

```
$this->profile
$this->account
```